# flexypool for DB2 and Oracle Datasources

Tags: java, database, oracle, connection-pooling, flexy-pool

We uses the below connection pools in our application

**1) DB2DataSource 
 2) OracleDataSource**

Can we implement flexypool metrics and failover strategies to the above connection pools? 
I didn't find any specific doc or example code related to it
under vladmihalcea's flexypool github repository.

Could you please suggest on this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can. You just need to use a connection pool like HikaricP in front of these two `DataSources`, and you'll get all the functionality offered by FlexyPool.